# How can I execute a plugin from a test method?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I've added a test project to my solution where I want to test the integrations, and by that testing the plugins from my local machine. I've added Microsoft.Crm.Tooling.Connector and have a connection to my test instance. But I'm unsure on how and what the configuration and service is set up.

```
        var crm = new CrmServiceClient(crmConnectionString);
        crm.OrganizationServiceProxy.EnableProxyTypes();

        var service = crm.OrganizationServiceProxy;

        var unsecureConfig = "?";
        var secureConfig = "?";

        var plugin = new ExternalWorkorder_OnCreate(unsecureConfig, secureConfig);
        plugin.ExecutePluginLogic(service?);
```

For executing the plugin, does the configuration matter? As long as i have the IServiceProvider, and how do I get that? Can I get it from CrmServiceClient? Or the OrganizationServiceProxy?

Answer (score 0):

No you do not need t worry about secure and unsecure config.

Look at [this article](https://carldesouza.com/connecting-to-dynamics-365-using-crmserviceclient/) which will connect to dynamics and perform operations as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the configuration if youre not counting on it in Plugin. But depending on how the plugin code is structured you will need to provide some even empty configuration.

I would recommend using FakeXrmEasy. https://dynamicsvalue.com/home

There are many examples on how to use the library.